# Derived category of dg modules vs. graded modules over a formal dg-algebra

Tags: derived-categories, differential-graded-algebras, koszul-duality

Let $R = \oplus_{i\geq0} R_i$, $R_0 = k$ ($k$ a field) be a positively-graded commutative noetherian algebra, regarded as an augmented dg-algebra with zero differential.

Depending on one's interest, one may form $\mathrm{D}^b(R\text{-grmod})$, the derived category of *graded* $R$-modules with finitely generated, bounded cohomology. Alternatively, one may form $\mathrm{D}^b(R\text{-dgmod})$, the derived category of *dg*-modules with locally finite, bounded cohomology.

Is there a way to compare these two categories? I am far from an expert, but to me it seems that $\mathrm{D}^b(R\text{-grmod}) \subset \mathrm{D}^b(R\text{-dgmod})$ (perhaps the inclusion is not rigorously true but intuitively true). However I am unable to find any such relationship in the literature.

If the context helps, I am interested in the case where $R$ is Koszul.

Comment: One has a functor from $D^b(R-grmod)$ to D^b(dgmod)$ and it is one way of understanding Koszul duality. For more see the introduction to "modular Koszul duality", by Soergel, Riche and myself.